# Difficulty in understand proof of product measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

we have $(\Omega_1,S_1,\mu_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,S_2,\mu_2)$ be two measure spaces and $S_1\times S_2=\{A\times B:A\in S_1 and B\in S_2\}$.Then we have defined a set function $\mu_1\times \mu_2:S_1\times S_2\to [0,\infty]$ defined by $\mu_1\times\mu_2(A\times B)=\mu_1(A)\times \mu_2(B)$.Now we have to prove that this set function is measure so for that we need to prove two things
(1) $\mu_1\times\mu_2(\phi\times\phi)=0$
(2) $\mu_1\times\mu_2$ is countably additive
In the proof of the 2nd property, we have assumed that let $\{A_n\times B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a disjoint sequence in $S_1\times S_2$ such that 
$A\times B$= $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\times B_n)\in S_1\times S_2$ we have to show that $\mu_1\times\mu_2(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\times B_n))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_1\times\mu_2(A_n\times B_n)$.
My question is that in the proof of this the book I am referring they have said that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\subseteq A$ but I think this should be equal since suppose if I choose $(a,b)\in A\times B$ this implies $(a,b)\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n\times B_n)$ which means $(a,b)\in A_n\times B_n$ for some $n$ which implies $a\in A_n\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ which implies $A\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ ,if it is wrong then where I am making mistak??

Comment: I agree with the statement that if $A\times B  =\cup A_n \times B_n$ (and $B\neq \emptyset$) then $A \subseteq \cup A_n$.

For their side of the implication  ($\cup A_n \subseteq A$) you also need the condition $B_n \neq \emptyset \forall n$ to hold.

Comment: But I'm surprised of your book's definition because $S_1 \times S_2$ defined this way is **not** a $\sigma$-algebra. We usually define measures on $\sigma$-algebras, and for that reason we introduce the product $\sigma$-algebra (which generated by $S_1\times S_2$) on which to define the product measure.

Comment: @justt But $S_1\times S_2$ is an algebra; the set function defined there is often called a "premeasure"...

Comment: Errr, I don't think so, it does not even have closure under finite union.